# R: Add day/night column to data frame, when sunrise/sunset times change

Tags: r, datetime, time

I have a data set like this over 23 days:

```
        temp1   DateTime
      1   448   2016-03-24   21:14:00
      2   448   2016-03-24   21:14:01
      3   448   2016-03-24   21:14:02
      4   448   2016-03-24   21:14:03
      5   448   2016-03-24   21:14:04
      6   448   2016-03-24   21:14:05
1930724   500   2016-04-15   13:46:21
1930725   500   2016-04-15   13:46:22
1930726   500   2016-04-15   13:46:23
1930727   500   2016-04-15   13:46:24
1930728   500   2016-04-15   13:46:25
1930729   500   2016-04-15   13:46:26
```

I now want to add a new column, that writes `day` for every `DateTime` - value greater than the `sunrise time` and smaller than the `sunset time`, so I get:

```
      temp1   DateTime                 dayNight
      1   448   2016-03-24   21:14:00  night
      2   448   2016-03-24   21:14:01  night
      3   448   2016-03-24   21:14:02  night
      4   448   2016-03-24   21:14:03  night
      5   448   2016-03-24   21:14:04  night
      6   448   2016-03-24   21:14:05  night
1930724   500   2016-04-15   13:46:21  day
1930725   500   2016-04-15   13:46:22  day
1930726   500   2016-04-15   13:46:23  day
1930727   500   2016-04-15   13:46:24  day
1930728   500   2016-04-15   13:46:25  day
1930729   500   2016-04-15   13:46:26  day
```

I get the times for sunrise and sunset like `"2016-04-15 06:40:37 UTC"` from the functions:

```
sunRise <- function(x){
sunrise.set(lat, long, x, timezone = "UTC", num.days = 1)[1,1]
}
```

and

```
sunSet <- function(x){
sunrise.set(lat, long, x, timezone = "UTC", num.days = 1)[1,2]
}
```

with the `sunrise.set()`- function from the package `StreamMetabolism`, with `lat <- 28.39675` and `long <- -16.567131`

Now the issue is that those sun times change over the 23 days of my data frame.

I there a way to make my `dayNight` column, based on the specific sunrise/-set times for every single day?

And is there a way to add the sunrise/-set times of every day as a column to the data frame?

Comment: What do `sunRise()` and `sunSet()` return?

Comment: You should look at constructing the sunrise and sunset table by date, adding a date column in the original data frame using dateTime field, then use `inner_join` from `dplyr` or `merge` from base to get everything organized. I can't provide working code since the input data you provided is incomplete.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! The two functions return date and time like this: `"2016-04-15 06:40:37 UTC"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one approach (based on my comment) and made up data I could come up with:

```
library(dplyr)

# You don't need this line if you already have DateTime in proper format
df$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(df$DateTime)

# Add a date column (with whatever timezone you want)
df$date <- as.Date(df$DateTime, tz = 'EST')

# Following generates the sunrise and sunset times for the two example dates
sunRise <- c(as.POSIXct('2016-04-15 06:40:37'), as.POSIXct('2016-03-24 06:55:00'))
sunSet <- c(as.POSIXct('2016-04-15 18:40:37'), as.POSIXct('2016-03-24 18:25:00'))
sun <- data.frame(date = as.Date(sunRise, tz = 'EST'), sunRise = sunRise, sunSet = sunSet)
sun
        date             sunRise              sunSet
1 2016-04-15 2016-04-15 06:40:37 2016-04-15 18:40:37
2 2016-03-24 2016-03-24 06:55:00 2016-03-24 18:25:00

# Join the two tables and compute night/day
df <- inner_join(df, sun)
df$dayNight <- ifelse(df$DateTime > df$sunRise & df$DateTime < df$sunSet, 'day', 'night')
```

Output is as follows:

```
df
   temp1            DateTime       date             sunRise              sunSet dayNight
1    448 2016-03-24 21:14:00 2016-03-24 2016-03-24 06:55:00 2016-03-24 18:25:00    night
2    448 2016-03-24 21:14:01 2016-03-24 2016-03-24 06:55:00 2016-03-24 18:25:00    night
3    448 2016-03-24 21:14:02 2016-03-24 2016-03-24 06:55:00 2016-03-24 18:25:00    night
4    448 2016-03-24 21:14:03 2016-03-24 2016-03-24 06:55:00 2016-03-24 18:25:00    night
5    448 2016-03-24 21:14:04 2016-03-24 2016-03-24 06:55:00 2016-03-24 18:25:00    night
6    448 2016-03-24 21:14:05 2016-03-24 2016-03-24 06:55:00 2016-03-24 18:25:00    night
7    500 2016-04-15 13:46:21 2016-04-15 2016-04-15 06:40:37 2016-04-15 18:40:37      day
8    500 2016-04-15 13:46:22 2016-04-15 2016-04-15 06:40:37 2016-04-15 18:40:37      day
9    500 2016-04-15 13:46:23 2016-04-15 2016-04-15 06:40:37 2016-04-15 18:40:37      day
10   500 2016-04-15 13:46:24 2016-04-15 2016-04-15 06:40:37 2016-04-15 18:40:37      day
11   500 2016-04-15 13:46:25 2016-04-15 2016-04-15 06:40:37 2016-04-15 18:40:37      day
12   500 2016-04-15 13:46:26 2016-04-15 2016-04-15 06:40:37 2016-04-15 18:40:37      day
```

Of course, you can remove unnecessary columns and retain what you want as follows:

```
df[, -c(3, 4, 5)]
   temp1            DateTime dayNight
1    448 2016-03-24 21:14:00    night
2    448 2016-03-24 21:14:01    night
3    448 2016-03-24 21:14:02    night
4    448 2016-03-24 21:14:03    night
5    448 2016-03-24 21:14:04    night
6    448 2016-03-24 21:14:05    night
7    500 2016-04-15 13:46:21      day
8    500 2016-04-15 13:46:22      day
9    500 2016-04-15 13:46:23      day
10   500 2016-04-15 13:46:24      day
11   500 2016-04-15 13:46:25      day
12   500 2016-04-15 13:46:26      day
```

Comment: Thanks! You also showed me how to easily remove multiple columns from the data frame - that's really helpful!